# Is there a way to do a random draw with filters?

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a random draw for employee performance reviews and need to filter the employees by shift and day 
**ex: only employees who work Monday Swing shift**

I have used the `=INDEX($A:$A,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($A:$A)),1)` formula for a random draw but seem to be unable to filter out different shifts.

My Data is basic with each employees name in the A column, the Day on the B column and Shift in C.

```
EX:
Tom     Monday     Grave
Ashley  Tuesday    Swing
Tom     Tuesday    Grave
Sally   Wednesday  Day
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, welcome to SO :-), The formula you have posted is working for me, what is the error message that you are getting? What exactly do you mean by `.. but seem to be unable to filter out different shifts`

Comment: He wants to be able to specify a shift, and then make a random selection only from people working in that shift.